# Reload fragments inside ViewPager which inside another fragment inViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-support-library

I have an activity, which includes ViewPager with three fragments. In the second fragment i have ViewPager with two different fragments too. 
This my MainActivityPagerAdapter which connected with ViewPager in MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivityPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter implements LoginView.LoginStateChangeListener {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivityPagerAdapter.class.getName();

    private MapFragment mapFragment = new MapFragment();
    private UserProfileFragment userProfileFragment = new UserProfileFragment();
    private CompanyProfileFragment CompanyProfileFragment = new DiveCenterProfileFragment();
    private NotificationsFragment notificationsFragment = new notificationsFragment();

    public MainActivityPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);

    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return mapFragment;
            case 1:
                return notificationsFragment;
            case 2:
                switch (MyApplication.getInstance().getSharedPreferenceHelper().getActiveUserType()) {
                    case DIVECENTER:
                        return companyProfileFragment;
                    case DIVER:
                    case INSTRUCTOR:
                        return userProfileFragment;
                    case NONE:
                        return userProfileFragment;
                }
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        Log.i(TAG, "getItemPosition");
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

This my pager adapter for ViewPager at the second fragment:

```
public class NotificationsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private PersonalNotificationsFragment personalNotificationsFragment = new PersonalNotificationsFragment();
    private ActivityNotificationsFragment activityNotificationsFragment = new ActivityNotificationsFragment();

    public NotificationsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return personalNotificationsFragment;
            case 1:
                return activityNotificationsFragment;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    public void setPersonalNotificationsFragment(PersonalNotificationsFragment personalNotificationsFragment) {
        this.personalNotificationsFragment = personalNotificationsFragment;
    }

    public void setActivityNotificationsFragment(ActivityNotificationsFragment activityNotificationsFragment) {
        this.activityNotificationsFragment = activityNotificationsFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

So, there are two user types in app:

- Simple user
- Company

When user changing his type i need to refresh all fragments in MainActivity including fragments inside second fragment. For this I'm using notifyDataSetChanged() for MainActivityViewPager, it work correctly, but fragments inside second fragment don't update(onCreateView don't called, and i see only empty views).
In what may be a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use getChildFragmentManager() for inner viewPager

Answer (score 0):

Use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` for changing fragments inside the **viewPager**